# PHP error using parenthesis in if construction

Tags: php

When I use this if construction with parenthesis

```
if ($_POST['type']!='1' || ($_POST['type']=='1' && $_POST['prepayment']=='2'))
{
     do this and that 
}
```

I get a PHP error:

Fatal error : Call to undefined function () in .....

What's wrong?

Comment: use it as `if (($_POST['type'] != '1') || ($_POST['type'] == '1' && $_POST['prepayment'] == '2')) {`

Comment: There isn't any error with the code, check this.

https://eval.in/590545

Comment: Still Fatal Error. I use PHP 5.5.15 - maybe PHP wrong settings ?

Comment: Could you paste the full error message? Does the line number match the `if` block?

Comment: Fatal error : Call to undefined function () in `path/file.php` on line 274. The line number matches exactly the `if` block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function name is given as "" (nothing), the only reasonable cause for this is a wrong whitespace character before `(`, e.g. an IDEOGRAPHIC SPACE U+3000, or something of that sort. PHP recognises that as not-a-space but some-Unicode-character, which is a valid function name. E.g. `漢字()` would be a valid function call, so is 　`()` (that's a full-width space character).

Check your spaces and/or retype that line.

Comment: I removed whitespace and its gone. To check it, I inserted the spaces again but it's still gone - weired. Maybe this is an error of the script interpreter / compiler. I'll watch this and come back later.

Comment: Again, this easily happens if you inadvertently insert some weird whitespace characters. Perhaps you're typing with an IME in a foreign language which may contain such characters, or you've copy and pasted from a weird source.

Comment: Constantly happening to me, accidentally press some combination of Shift, Ctrl, and Space which results in a non-breaking space which renders as a space in editors.

Comment: @deceze - Well I use XCode as editor with UTF-8 - really weired. I accept youre answer but might come back to report upcoming errors